# Error 1129: Host '' blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

Tags: mysql, sql, security, database-administration

When I run a python code which connects to mysql, I see this error; "Error 1129: Host '' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'".

**Here is what I have tried:** 
I increased max_connection_errors values and I also executed 'flush hosts' command. I also checked mysql log, but there is none. In addition, I checked network connection, and it's fine too.

$netstat -an | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

**Here is mysql setting:**

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%error%';

error_count        | 0
log_error          | /var/log/mysql/error.log 
max_connect_errors | 4294967295
max_error_count    | 64
slave_skip_errors  | OFF

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%max_connections%';

max_connections | 5000

mysql> show status like '%onn%';

Aborted_connects         | 6
Connections              | 4802
Max_used_connections     | 26
Ssl_client_connects      | 0
Ssl_connect_renegotiates | 0
Ssl_finished_connects    | 0
Threads_connected        | 1

mysql>'SHOW STATUS WHERE variable_name LIKE "Threads_%" OR variable_name = "Connections

Connections       | 4996
Threads_cached    | 7
Threads_connected | 1
Threads_created   | 1950
Threads_running   | 1

mysql> show processlist;

4800 | root | localhost | NULL            | Query   |    0 | NULL  | show processlist
4807 | root | localhost | db1 | Sleep   |    0 |       | NULL

Can anyone please help me find what went wrong and what's the way to fix it?

Comment: You should ask this on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BK435 Python and mysql are in the same server.

Comment: Also, the mysql error was generated immediately when I ran a code. The code didn't even fail and didn't generate any error. I also checked on /var/log and no fail and no error.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a fault in your MySQL server software. It's evidence of a fault in some other software running on the same machine you're using to run your python program.  Error 1129 means MySQL's crude anti-cybercriminal feature has been activated: programs running on the same machine you're using have tried and failed to connect many times (100 by default). When that happens MySQL concludes the machine is compromised (or running amok) and refuses to accept any more connections from it.

What could cause this? Is there a cronjob or other automatically running program on your machine that's rigged up with an invalid user name or password? If so, it might be hammering away on the MySQL server racking up connection failures.

If it's a Linux or BSD-based machine use the `ps axuww` shell command a few times and look for processes you don't recognize. (If you're not sure about how to do that ask on the forum for your operating system.)

You might consider rebooting the machine.

**Edit** Your machine seems to be under attack. You mentioned that you're getting a lot of `failed password` messages in your authlog. Can you track down the source of these attacks? If they're internal -- that is, from a machine you or your colleagues control -- they are probably some kind of program that's configured

- to run too often, or
- to use an incorrect password,
- or both.

Look for a pattern in the ip addresses. Do these failures come from one or a very few addresses? Are they from private addresses like 192.168.*.* or 10.*.*.*, or even from localhost (127.0.0.1)? Or do they come from all over the place? If you don't recognize the addresses, try putting them into the forms in these three web sites:

```
https://ripe.net
https://apnic.net
https://arin.net
```

At least one of these three will tell you the country and telecom provider from which the failures are coming. If they're from someplace where you have no relationships you are under attack.

If the attacks are external, you need to take steps to block them before they reach your database machine. Most machines running MySQL are **isolated** from the wider internet by firewalls because MySQL isn't as robust as some other software against cybercriminal and script-kiddie attack.

Look for a timing pattern.  Is the timing of these failures once every five minutes, or is it as rapid as possible, or what?   If it's regular, it seems likely that you have some sort of misbehaving program someplace.

If none of this makes sense to you, **ask a network engineer to help you**. If your MySQL server holds sensitive or valuable information, **don't delay in confronting this problem**.  Good luck. This kind of thing has ruined some days for me.

Comment: Thanks @Ollie Jones. I checked /var/log/authlog and I see a lot of "Failed password for root from <ip address>" and "authentication failure" from all the different ip addresses. Maybe this would be the cause of Error 1129. I also rebooted the machine, but I see the same error. What action should I take next? Can I not take suspicious ip address connection?

Comment: @BK435, you mentioned above that I should allow remote connections. But  instead of skip-networking, I set that the default is to listen only on localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure. Host 'X' here in Host 'X' blocked because of many connection errors is localhost DNS.

Comment: You are an angel to me, @Ollie Jones! Thanks so much. I noticed there were a lot suspicious connection fail such as "sshd[3040]: Failed password for root from.. " or "sshd[8726]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname=". I installed fail2ban and it already banned many ip addresses. But even after this, I still see the same error, "Host '' blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'" when I run a python code. I restarted mysql and rebooted server but it's the same error. We don't have network engineer here and I'm really lost. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

A client must have hit many connection requests in a same time frame.
reset solution remove host IP (s) from block list by running command `mysqladmin flush-hosts`